# How Record WEB Application and test load/Performance in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I tried to test one WEB application. I log in to the application and then go to diff. menu. In JMeter, I used "HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder" to record the application after stopping the recording many requests are created and I tried to run those requests then some requests failed it shows error 403, "Invalid username and password ". Here I also used a recording controller.
So I need help to test the load /performance of my web application for multiple users so how is it achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that "many" requests should be created, I can think of 3:

1. Open login page
2. Perform login
3. Go to "diff" menu

If you're seeing "many" requests most probably you're recording a lot of stuff that you should not be recording like [embedded resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses/)

There is [Recording Template](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#basic-instructions) which is kind of handy, it has pre-defined patterns for excluding of common file types which you should not be recording

[image]

Also be aware that in the majority of cases you won't be able to successfully replay a set of recorded requests without [correlating](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) the dynamic parameters.